# Pandas include single row in df after filtering with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, filter

So, in this function:

```py
def filter_by_freq(df, frequency):
    filtered_df = df.copy()
    
    if frequency.upper() == 'DAY':
        pass
        
    else:
        date_obj = filtered_df['Date'].values[0]
        target_day = pd.to_datetime(date_obj).day
        target_month = pd.to_datetime(date_obj).month
        
        final_date_obj = filtered_df['Date'].values[-1]
        
        if frequency.upper() == 'MONTH':
            filtered_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df['Date'].dt.day.eq(target_day)]
        
        elif frequency.upper() == 'YEAR':
            filtered_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df['Date'].dt.day.eq(target_day)]
            filtered_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df['Date'].dt.month.eq(target_month)]
    
    return filtered_df
```

How can I also include in the `.loc` the very last row from the original df? Tried doing (for month frequency): `filtered_df = filtered_df.loc[(filtered_df['Date'].dt.day.eq(target_day)) | (filtered_df['Date'].dt.date.eq(final_date_obj))]` but didn't work.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it. In this example I have a df and I want to filter out all rows that have `c1 > 0.5`, but I want to keep the last row no matter what. I create a boolean series called `lte_half` to keep track of the first condition, and then I create another boolean series/list/array (all interchangeable) called `end_ind` which is `True` only for the last row. The filtered table is created by taking all rows that pass either condition with the `|`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':np.random.rand(20)})
lte_half = df['c1'].le(0.5)
end_ind = df.index == df.index[-1]

filt_df = df[lte_half | end_ind]
print(filt_df)
```

[image]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xvmnnZ1K7Wyr this returned a df with no filter applied whatsoever

Comment: your screenshot doesn't show how you made `end_filter`. did the above example code work for you?

Comment: oh also you probably want `filtered_df[(freq_filter & freq_filter2) | end_filter]` because both the two freq filters have to be true right?

Comment: My bad, `end_filter` is a copy paste from your `end_ind` example, will try out the `&` operator :)

Comment: can you edit your question and paste in the output of your `print(df.head(20).to_dict())` so I can try on your data?

Comment: It actually worked, I had changed something to test it out before the `&` and forgot to change back, marked your post as solution, thank you! :)